# Sealed-Partial Class

Tags: c#

Can you make a `partial` class file for a class that is `sealed`?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Open Visual Studio and try it.

Comment: Since there's no link between partition of classes into multiple files and inheritance my guess is yes but as Jay says try it

Comment: "It's easy to try" isn't a reason not to ask here.

Comment: In my case I was doing `partial sealed` which doesn't compile (`sealed partial` is the correct usage).

Answer (score 27):

The `sealed` keyword simply means that the class cannot be inherited. It has no impact on how the class' code is structured otherwise. The `partial` keyword simply allows a class to be split among several files.

In the sample below, class A compiles just fine. B does not compile because A is sealed and inheritance is not allowed.

```
public sealed partial class A   { private int x; }

public sealed partial class A   { private int y; }

public class B : A  {   }
```

Comment: What if, in the split files, one class definition is marked partial and the other is not? What takes precedence?

Answer (score 5):

It seemed to compile fine.

```
sealed partial class Class1
{
    public void MyMethod() { }
}

partial class Class1
{
    public void MyMethod2() { }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is more informative because signature of class will be merged on compilation. So it is enough to specify only one part as sealed. And to determine if class is sealed you will need to check all its parts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sealed classes only block inheritence. Partial classes are not inherited; they are merged to one class as soon as you compile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make partial class which is sealed.

Ex : Public Sealed Partial class Employee